# Ionic V1 Cordova undefined

Tags: ionic-v1

I recently found out that on my project window.cordova is undefined which it wasn't before clearly.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Window is defined basically but all stuff with cordova.js is undefined. Also tried to integrate it manually but it won't work.

Is anyone experiencing the same issues? It was all fine in the last weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new CLI messed it up, I downgraded and it runs again. So for v1 version its obviously a little bit problematic.

Comment: I rolled back that edit; your question should remain strictly a question.